# same fql(facebook Query Language) shows different result in graph explorer and embedded in javascript code

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am developing hybrid app using cordova, app is intergated with facebook for which i used android SDK.
I need uid of friends of user, for I am using following fql

```
SELECT name,uid 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT target_id 
              FROM connection 
              WHERE source_id=me() and is_following=1) 
ORDER BY name Asc
```

which is showing different uid in graph API Explorer and in logcat(android ide)

result in graph API Explorer

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Bharata Dumbo", 
      "uid": "817899964906568"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Deendayal Sharma", 
      "uid": "807134486015575"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Indravadan Intwala", 
      "uid": "813727452007073"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Manisha Parmar", 
      "uid": "10205158153335480"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Nitin Shah", 
      "uid": "1260451067"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Nitin Shah", 
      "uid": "100005623513169"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Smita Vora", 
      "uid": "323986007788625"
    }
  ]
}


where as result in logcat::

    Response getPageLike: `{"data":[{"uid":"100000597166472","name":"Bharata Dumbo"},{"uid":"792885570773800","name":"Deendayal Sharma"},{"uid":"813635845349567","name":"Indravadan Intwala"},{"uid":"10204471863338659","name":"Manisha Parmar"},{"uid":"1260451067","name":"Nitin Shah"},{"uid":"100005623513169","name":"Nitin Shah"},{"uid":"316474181873141","name":"Smita Vora"}]}`
```

Comment: as any one can see the uid of Bharata Dumbo is 817899964906568 in explorer where as it is different logcat 100000597166472.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your app is a Graph API >=v2.0 app, that means it uses app-scoped ids instead of global ids as with v1.0.

The Graph Explorer sometimes inherently uses v1.0 (global ids respectively), even if another version is selected from the pulldown.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api